# Как сравнить два плоских файла/мапы в java

Tags: java, сортировка, map, set, treemap

Всем, привет, попробую быть кратким.
Есть задача - мне нужно сравнить два плоских файла и вывести разницу в таком формате

```
  chars1: [a, b, c] 
- chars2: [d, e, f]
+ chars2: false
- checked: false
+ checked: true
```

Где, если строка (ключ-значение) был одинаков и в 1ом и во 2ом файле - оставить ключ-значение без изменений, если в 1ом файле ключ был, а во 2ом был удален или изменен - добавить перед ключом знак "-", а если в 1ом файле ключа не было,а во 2ом появился - добавить перед ключом знак "+"

Ниже пример моего кода. Сейчас он не работает корректно, выдает пустые скобки {}

ПС. У меня есть простой парсер файлов - Parser.parser(), реализован в другом классе, который ищет файлы по абсолютным / относительным ссылкам, он работает корректно, был проверен ранее, когда у меня был другой основной код и вся инфа выводилась. Щас код не воркает, я голову сломал над проблемой

Код:

```
 public class Differ {
  public static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> generate(String path1, String path2) throws IOException {
    String resultString = "{ \n";

    TreeMap<String, Object> map1 = Parser.parser(path1);
    TreeMap<String, Object> map2 = Parser.parser(path2);

    TreeMap<String, Status> mapWithStatusKeys = compareMaps(map1, map2);

    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(map1.keySet());
    Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>(map2.keySet());
    set.addAll(set2);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (var key : set) {
        if (mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).equals("unchanged")) {
            resultMap.put(key, map1.get(key));
            resultString += " ".repeat(4) + key + ": " + map1.get(key) + "\n";
        } else if (mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).equals("changed")) {
            resultMap.put("-" + key, map1.get(key));
            resultMap.put("+" + key, map2.get(key));
            resultString += " ".repeat(2) + "-" + key + ": " + map1.get(key) + "\n";
            resultString += " ".repeat(2) + "+" + key + ": " + map2.get(key) + "\n";
        } else if (mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).equals("deleted")) {
            resultMap.put("-" + key, map1.get(key));
            resultString += " ".repeat(2) + "-" + key + ": " + map1.get(key) + "\n";
        } else if (mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).equals("added")) {
            resultMap.put("+" + key, map2.get(key));
            resultString += " ".repeat(2) + "+" + key + ": " + map2.get(key) + "\n";
        }
    }
    resultString += "}";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
    return resultMap;
}

public static TreeMap<String, Status> compareMaps(TreeMap<String, Object> map1, TreeMap<String, Object> map2) {
    String resultString = "{ \n";
    TreeMap<String, Status> resultMap = new TreeMap<>();

    for (String everyKey : map1.keySet()) {
        String key = everyKey;
        Object value1 = map1.get(everyKey);

        if (map2.containsKey(everyKey)) {
            Object value2 = map2.get(everyKey);
            if (compareValues(value1, value2)) {            
                resultMap.put(key, new Status(key, "unchanged"));
            } else {
                resultMap.put(key, new Status(key, "changed"));
            }
        } else {
            resultMap.put(key, new Status(key, "deleted"));
        }
    }

    for (String everyKey : map2.keySet()) {
        String key = everyKey;
        Object value2 = map2.get(everyKey);

        if (!map1.containsKey(everyKey)) {
            resultMap.put(key, new Status(key, "added"));
        }
    }

    return resultMap;

}

public static boolean compareValues(Object value1, Object value2) {
    if (value1 == null && value2 == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (value1 == null || value2 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return value1.toString().equals(value2.toString());
}
```

Класс статус:

```
public class Status {
private final String value;
private final String status;

public Status(String value, String status) {
    this.value = value;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String isStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем затуп. Мне нужно

1. Создать структуру, которая будет содержать разницу между двумя файлами(мапами), я думаю использтовать линкедХэшМэп, и вносить туда значения, изменяя ключи, так я сохраню все значения и сохраню порядок добавления.
2. Вывести в итоге отформатированную сроку - разницу.

Это все пытаюсь сделать в цикле фор основного метода generate. Код не работает, может кто-то подсказть в чем дело? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка простейшая, сразу ее нашел почти.

В цикле фор, коий обходит все значения по сету я неправильно брал из мапы mapWithStatusKeys,я брал mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).equals("unchanged"), и в итоге я пытался сравнить со строкой unchanged объект класса Status, изменил условия на такое:

```
if (mapWithStatusKeys.get(key).isStatus().equals("unchanged"))
```

все пофиксилось!:)

Мб кому-то будет полезно